# Have a IDE Scaling issue in VS2017 Winforms Application

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2017, windows-10, dpi, autoscaling

I've googled this, and wasn't able to find exactly what I needed. So I will present it here and see if there is quick setting I can change that solves this issue.

My issue is one of Scaling, but not in the run-time sense as you (and Google) would suspect. Rather it's in the VS2017 designer itself, in that the point location settings for controls on a form wont stay consistent from one resolution to another. Here is what I mean:

1. Workstation @ work is Windows 10 (v1709), on dual 1920 x 1080 monitors.
2. Workstation @ home is Windows 10 (v1709), on triple 4k monitors (dual GTX-1080's in SLI).

Same project (working on it at work and home).

When I open the designer @ home, naturally everything is smaller.. but some control items are 'out of place' point wise. So I adjust them and continue on. When I get to work, I have to adjust those same controls yet again.

Now I am already guessing (and I haven't tested this yet) that this is due to the fact that I have the Scale, in the Display settings on my home workstation, set to 125% (because everything is VERY tiny on a 4K monitor if set to 100%). But I thought the IDE in VS2017 would compensate accordingly, without adjusting the **actual** point values for control locations...

Or is there another setting I am missing, in VS2017 itself, that will allow the forms to keep consistency between environment resolutions?

**UPDATE 07/25/2018:** I set the Scaling down to 100% and checked to see if that made a difference. It did not! So I set the resolution, of my main display, to 1920 x 1080. That had no affect either. I am totally at a loss here, as I have never experienced anything like this before. Controls are out of place, and the fonts are larger than what is displayed on my workstation at work. I didn't make any corrections this time, so everything will look as it should when I get back to work.

However, I am thinking that this may **entirely** be a display issue, as Visual Studio is not seeing a change (i.e. does not prompt to SAVE) in any of the forms when I close the project.

Monitor DPI difference (*stretching.. need rope here*)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I actually found the answer to this dilemma on here, [in this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44898945/different-and-wrong-size-of-a-winforms-form-on-high-resolution-screen-in-vs-ide).

It essentially states what I suspected. It's a DPI issue. The posting mentions a [work-around](https://code4ward.net/2016/11/29/visual-studio-winforms-designer-on-highdpi/), but it's not a complete solution as there are trade-offs.

So I guess I will have to get an actual 1920 x 1080 monitor in order to work on Winforms applications at home.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio on a high-DPI monitor. I'm currently using it at full resolution on a 4K laptop screen at 225% and my Winforms designer is working fine. You'll have to put up with VS having blurry fonts, but at least it becomes usable again, and without having to change monitors! This article was very helpful, and provides a registry fix for the problem:

https://code4ward.net/2016/11/29/visual-studio-winforms-designer-on-highdpi/

Comment: Hah! I just followed the link to the posting in your answer and saw an answer there pointing to the same article! Hope it helps anyway!